# how to upload two image using two different field in form to ms Access Data base using Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUq13.jpg4)

```
                  <form class="form1" name="myform" action="try1.asp" 
                   method="post" id="myform" 
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
                  <input type="file"  id="files1" name="s_bcp" 
                  ext="jpg,jpeg,png" value="" >
                  <input type="file"  id="files2" name="s1_bcp" 
                  ext="jpg,jpeg,png" value="" >
                  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Imagedatabase>
                  Database">
                 </form>
```

When the user clicks, the two images have to be saved in two different fields of the database table.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a third party component to do that. I suggest www.aspupload.com